# Jupyter and Python - Passing css colors to a div tag from a dictionary

Tags: python, css, jupyter

In my Notebook, I extract some arrays from my main database, create a HTML tittle for them and display the results.

Each of these arrays have a particular color attached to it, and I'd like to show this color on their tittle.

I tried to do this by creating a dictionary for the color list :

```
colors_dpts = {
    '01' : 'AliceBlue',
    '02' : 'AntiqueWhite',
    '03' : 'Aqua',
    '04' : 'Aquamarine',
    '05' : 'Azure',
    '06' : 'Beige',
    '07' : 'Bisque'
    }
```

...and to display the color with something like this :

```
for dept in Nums_Departements.nums_dpts:
    [...]
    display(HTML(f"<div background-color:{Colors_Dpts.colors_dpts[dept]}>"))
    [...]
```

Sadly, there's no color in my output. Right now, I don't know if my Python code is wrong or there is another CSS style overwriting the style in my `<div>`...

So I think my main question is : is my method the right one ? Should I try with CSS variables ?

EDIT: add a precision after gimix' answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please do not just say "it doesn't work": what happens exactly? Anyhow your HTML seems wrong, at the very least you need to put a `style` attribute and then specify the `background-color` in the attribute's value

Comment: The missing `style` attribute was the answer! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by gimix, my HTML were wrong, with a `style' attribute missing.

With this corrected line :

```
 display(HTML(f"<div style='background-color:{Colors_Dpts.colors_dpts[dept]}'>"
```

All my titles receive their color correctly.

Thanks!